# Can two proofs rely on each other?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I have two proofs by induction. The inductive step of each relies on the other. Is it flawed to have a circular dependence like this?

Both proofs are regarding the existence of paths in a graph. In the first proof ($P$) we show that if a path (that meets a set of criteria) exists in graph $A$ then a corresponding path will exist in graph $B$, where paths correspond to each other if they share the same source and sink node. The second proof ($Q$) shows that if there are two paths (that meet a certain criteria) that share the same source node in $A$, then there will be two paths in $B$ that have the same sinks as the paths in $A$ that also share some source node. The proofs are by induction as some edges in the graph may be inferred due to the existence of a path.

For $P$ to work for a certain criteria of paths, I need $Q$ to be true. For $Q$ to work for a certain criteria of paths (different from the first), I need $P$ to be true.

Edit inspired by the comment from @Gae.S.: If it's helpful, for $P(n+1)$ to be true I need $Q(n)$ to be true, and for $Q(n)$ to be true I need $P(n-1)$ to be true.

Comment: You are talking in very general terms. Please give a short outline of each proof so that we can better understand what you mean.

Comment: It is true, for instance, that $P(0)\land Q(0)\land(\forall n\in\Bbb N) ((\neg P(n)\lor Q(n))\land(\neg Q(n)\lor P(n+1)))$ implies $(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(P(n)\land Q(n))$ by induction.

Comment: @TobyMak I have provided a high-level description. Let me know if you need something more! :)

Comment: Can't you merge the two inductions into one? For example, when trying to show that a sequence is increasing and bounded (say by m and M), it is easier to show by induction that $m \leqslant x_n < x_{n+1} \leqslant M$ for every $n$ than showing the two properties by induction separately.

Comment: @Taladris The purpose of the second proof is really to facilitate the first proof (which is the main lemma for the theorem). The criteria for the paths to be shown in each proof are different, and so I feel merging them would be like telling two different stories at the same time.

Comment: At least one of the proofs must be proven "from outside". If you have a proof for $A$ that relys on a proof for $B$ and vice cersa, this alone gives a circular argument.

Comment: @DavidPoxon: from your edit, it seems that you can prove that $P(n)\land Q(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)\land Q(n+1)$, right? Then you should try to use induction with $R(n)=P(n) \land Q(n)$.

Comment: @Taladris Yes, that's right. I'm pretty unaccustomed to proofs, as I'm sure you can tell; do you mean I need $P(n)∧Q(n)$ to be in both induction hypotheses?

Comment: @DavidPoxon: I mean $R(n)=P(n)\land Q(n)$ to be what you prove by induction. That is: 1) prove $R(0)$, that is $P(0)$ and $Q(0)$. 2) Assume that $R(n)$ is true for some $n\geqslant 0$ and show that $R(n+1)$ is then true. 3) Conclude: $R(n)$ (hence $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$) is true for every $n\geqslant 0$. From what I understand of your question, you actually already wrote all this, you just need to write it in the right order.

Comment: @Taladris awesome, I will do that. Thank you!